# nginx giving 404 for location a whereas it is working fine for location b

Tags: nginx

I am trying to serve a python app and a tomcat app from nginx. The tomcat app is running fine whereas python is giving 404. My files are:
1.

```
mysite.conf
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        return 301 https://mysite-url$request_uri;
           }
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        ssl on;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        ssl_ciphers  'ECDH !aNULL !eNULL !SSLv2 !SSLv3';
        ssl_certificate  /home/sslcerts/my.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /home/sslcerts/mykey.pem;

         server_name mydomain ;

location ^~/api/ {
  include proxy_params;
  proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/pyapi/pyapi.sock;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}

       location / {

 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

When I access `https://mysite/api`
error log says:

```
myIP - - [15/May/2020:13:26:03 +0000] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Whereas if I access `https://mysite`, it works absolutely fine. Any idea where am I missing?

I have a service running to serve gunicorn app for the python app.

Thanks

Comment: That looks like the access log. Is there anything in the Nginx error log?

Comment: Have you tried with a trailing slash at the end of  http://unix:/home/ubuntu/pyapi/pyapi.sock

Comment: solved it all, it was just that gunicorn was not listening to the port